# Dynamically change menus after login in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="dnaClientApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: item.route === menuActive }"><a href="#{{item.route}}">{{item.label}}</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

**MainCtrl main.js**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $rootScope, $location, $cookies, translationSvc, $http, $cookieStore, UserService) {

       if (typeof $scope.selectedLanguage === 'undefined') {

            $scope.selectedLanguage = 'fi';//Default language

        }
        translationSvc.getTranslation($scope, $scope.selectedLanguage);


        $scope.menu = translationSvc.getMenu($scope.selectedLanguage);//Creating menus dynamically
        console.log('$scope.menu-->' + $scope.menu + ' length: ' + $scope.menu.length);

        $scope.menuActive = '/';

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, curr, prev) {
            $scope.menuActive = $location.path();
        });
```

**translationSvc**

```
var getMenu = function($scope, language) {
        if (language === 'fi' && typeof $rootScope.userRole !== 'undefined' && typeof $rootScope.userRole.currentUserRole !== 'undefined' && $rootScope.userRole.currentUserRole.userRole === 3 ) {

            $scope.menu = [
                {label: 'Home', route: '#/'},
                {label: 'DNA', route: '#/dna'},
                {label: 'Dna-list', route: '#/dna-list'},
                {label: 'Admin', route: '#/admin'}

            ]

        }else...
```

**Routes after login goes here, menu is in index.html**

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
```

**Question**

If I check the length of menu array in controller, everything is ok, but my menus in header are all the same, default menus (3 menus, not 4). What am I doing wrong or why I can't update menus dynamically? Idea is to get different menus for different roles, like administrator could see a admin menu as well etc. Any other working ideas to get this done?

Comment: From where are you trying to modify $scope.menu ? Are you in the same controller ? MainCtrl ?

Comment: I call translationSvc from main controller and I create there dynamically menu and put it to the $scope. There is that else with three dots, it means that there is more options, but I save the code :)

Comment: Are all the tests in the `if` statement met?

Comment: Before login scope.menu in cosole is: $scope.menu--> length: 3 and after login with admin role $scope.menu-->length: 4 and I checked with debugger that everything is fine, but menu is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea of passing around `$scope` to services. It makes the service very confusing to read because you don't know what data it's changing. Instead, why not just build the menu in `translationSvc.getMenu()` and return it to `MainCtrl`. I don't see why something like this shouldn't work unless code that you didn't post is doing something else.

**Controller:**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $rootScope, $location, $cookies, translationSvc, $http, $cookieStore, UserService) {
    ...

    // Creating menus dynamically
    $scope.menu = translationSvc.getMenu($scope.selectedLanguage);

    ...
}
```

**translationSvc:**

```
var getMenu = function(language) {
    var newMenu = []

    if (language === 'fi' && typeof $rootScope.userRole !== 'undefined' && typeof $rootScope.userRole.currentUserRole !== 'undefined' && $rootScope.userRole.currentUserRole.userRole === 3 ) {

        newMenu = [
            {label: 'Home', route: '#/'},
            {label: 'DNA', route: '#/dna'},
            {label: 'Dna-list', route: '#/dna-list'},
            {label: 'Admin', route: '#/admin'}
        ];

    } else if (...) {
        newMenu = [...];
    } else {
        newMenu = [...];
    }

    return newMenu;
}
```

I think you were running into issues where you're updating the `$scope` outside of angular's realm, i.e. angular had no way of knowing that you were changing the `$scope` in `translationSvc` so your changes were not propagated to your view (`index.html`).

I also recommend editing `translationSvc.getTranslation()` along the same lines and remove passing the `$scope` to that function as well.

Comment: I rewrite the code so I don't pass the scope anymore, but the result is the same. I checked with debugger that menu in the scope is correct one, but index.html is always the same. $routeProvider for / goes to main.html and menu is in index.html.

Comment: I figured it out that if user changes the language, menus are correct. So it needs  $route.reload(); call to work correctly. But if I add this to mainCtrl init, it is eternal loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the digest loop is not performed when you change your menu.

Wrap it into $timeout to force the digest loop and do not forget to add $timeout as a dependency

```
$timeout(function(){
$scope.menu=translationSvc.getMenu($scope, $scope.selectedLanguage);//Creating menus dynamically
});
```

Comment: No help, but thank you anyway for idea. I think that I got some kind of logical mistake with scope between index.html and main.html as a part of index.html. This is irritating. Any other ideas for creating menus dynamically or get this working? BTW, what is the digest loop :)

Answer (score 0):

I added $viewContentLoaded and it started to work. There is that login-system between pages and I think that it might be a problem with restricted routes etc.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            $scope.menu = translationSvc.getMenu($scope.selectedLanguage);
        });
```